# Bind Html with variables in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I need to render some HTML I recibe from back. Something like this:

```
<strong> Item label: {{item.label}}</strong>
```

I try to do it with:

```
<div [innerHTML]="html"></div>
```

But its render:

```
Item label: {{item.label}}
```

But I have the item object

```
  item = {
    label : 'Label from item'   }
```

And I need to be render

```
Item label: Label from item
```

I create an example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-htmlwithvariables

Comment: You can't bind data like this way, but you can make it with another way like 
 html = `<strong> Item label: ${this.item.label}</strong>`

Answer (score 3):

## Use ES6 string interpolation

```
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-component',
      template: '<div [innerHtml]="html" ></div>',
      styleUrls: [ './app.component.scss' ]
    })
    export class AppComponent {
    
      item = {
        label: 'Label from item'
      };
      html: any = `<strong> Item label: ${this.item.label}</strong>`;
      
      constructor() { }
    
    }
```

> Template strings use back-ticks (``) rather than the single or double-quotes.
>
> Template strings can use placeholders for string substitution using the ${ } syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You can't bind data like this way, because you bind data after Angular compile HTML, so you can try with another way like

```
export class AppComponent  {
   name = 'Angular 6';
   searchterms = { answerId: 3 };
   item = { label : 'Label from item' }
   html = `<strong> Item label: ${this.item.label}</strong>`;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your component, make it like this:

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 6';
  searchterms = {
    answerId: 3
  };
  item = {
    label : 'Label from item'
  }
  html = '<strong> Item label:'+ this.item.label + '</strong>';

}
```

If you want it to render as a string template. use string interpolation:

```
html = `<strong> Item label:${this.item.label} </strong>`;
```